# Why I should use .add(new ArrayList<>(list)) when I add an arraylist to an arraylist of arraylist?

Tags: arraylist

I am solving a subset problem, and initialize an arraylist named list and an arraylist of arraylist named result. I should use `result.add(new ArrayList<>(list))` when add list to result. Could you please tell me why. The code is listed below. Many thanks.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (nums == null || nums.length == 0) {
        return result;
    }

    Arrays.sort(nums);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    subsetsHelper(nums, result, list, 0);
    return result;
}

public void subsetsHelper(int[] nums, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result, ArrayList<Integer> list, int start) {
    result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));
    for (int i = start; i < nums.length; ++i) {
        list.add(nums[i]);
        subsetsHelper(nums, result, list, i + 1);
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In subsetsHelper():

"list" wants to store Integers.

"result" wants to store ArrayLists of Integers.

`result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list))` could just be `result.add(list)`

All your line is doing is copying all items in list into a new `ArrayList<Integer>` first, then putting that ArrayList into result.

Comment: Hi has this answer helped you? If not please elaborate.